# How to share drive on windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing

I want to share my one drive on one computer with another computer connected to first computer through LAN so that I can install softwares from one computer to other computer.

How can I do that?

One computer contains the setup files on the drive that I want to share. I want to access those setup files through other computer so that I can run setup from other computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this tutorial for how to create a network share: [Create a network share](http://www.homenethelp.com/web/howto/net-share-xp.asp)

This will show you how to make the setup files on the first computer visible to the second one, so that you can run them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it like that. Almost all software makes more than just files, it adds registry entries, sometimes sets environmental variables, etc. This cannot be created on a computer through a simple drive share.